# How to get UIBezierPath of shape in UIImage or crop UIImage in a certain shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uibezierpath

I am new in iOS, I want to know if I can get the `UIBezierPath` of a `UIImage`. I have a `UIImage` of face layout and want to get the `UIBezierPath`, which helps me in cropping the `UIImage`.
Or, can any one tell me about other ways of cropping `UIImage`s?, but make sure cropping is in a custom shape (like: face, heart etc), not in a rectangle.

Comment: have you acheived this ? I need similar functionality but below code is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code **to mask image with image**:

```
- (UIImage *)cerateImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image
                    withMaskImage:(UIImage *)mask {
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
    CGImageRef maskRef = mask.CGImage;

    CGImageRef imageMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                             CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                             CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                             CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef),
                                             NULL,
                                             YES);

    CGImageRef maskedReference = CGImageCreateWithMask(imageRef, imageMask);
    CGImageRelease(imageMask);

    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedReference];
    CGImageRelease(maskedReference);

    return maskedImage;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Photo.png"];
UIImage *mask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Mask.png"];
self.imageView.image = [self cerateImageFromImage:image
                                     withMaskImage:mask];
```

Comment: I am very thankful to you for such a quick response, but sorry to say i am unable to get desire result from this code. when i create image of face layout, it gives me an oval shape image which have some missing part from top on both side, left and right hand side.

Comment: Oh, so you have a mask image and want to use to crop another image?

Comment: Keenle, Unable to get the result, it returns me "nill" value. I already try this code, i don't know why all this happing. I use this code in this way:
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Some image from camera or person face"];
UIImage *mask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"face layout image"];

and then call the method.

Comment: Before `cerateImageFromImage:withImageMask:` method call try to put break point and verify that you are passing non `nil` valies.

Comment: I also try this all both the images have value but when the code pass to the "imageMask", it give "nill" value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57366/discussion-between-keenle-and-syed-sharjeel-ali).

Comment: I'm having a strange problem with this. When I apply a mask and show the result on a UIImageView, it works fine, but when saving the resulting image using UIImagePNGRepresentation, I get the original image saved, without the mask applied.

Comment: @PauloCesar How did you get the image. Can you share the code?

Comment: @Dalvik here's my code: https://gist.github.com/puelocesar/d3f0bbed74d97ec94de212e17e7adba1

Comment: how to crop face size shape certain image objective c? keenly sir